# React-native build fail: "Could not create task ':app:copyDownloadableDepsToLibs'"

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, build.gradle

I'm trying to run my **react native app** on my usb connected android device. Yesterday it worked perfectly, but today, without changing anything, `npx react-native run-android` command fails with this error (*'.../android/app/build.gradle'*):

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> Could not create task '**:app:copyDownloadableDepsToLibs**'.
>
> **Could not create task of type 'Copy'.**
>         org/gradle/api/internal/file/copy/**DefaultCopySpec**

My attempt of `cd android` and then `./gradlew clean` also failed with the same error. I tried to delete the build folder, I also ran `npm install` but no success.

Here is my ...android/app/**build.gradle** file:

```js
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    import com.android.build.OutputFile

    /**
     * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
     * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
     * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
     * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
     * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
     * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
     * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
     *
     * project.ext.react = [
     *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
     *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
     *
     *   // the entry file for bundle generation
     *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
     *
     *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
     *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
     *   bundleInDebug: false,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
     *   bundleInRelease: true,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
     *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
     *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
     *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
     *   // bundleInBeta: true,
     *
     *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
     *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
     *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
     *
     *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
     *   root: "../../",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
     *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
     *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
     *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
     *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
     *
     *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
     *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
     *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
     *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
     *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
     *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
     *
     *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
     *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
     *
     *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
     *   extraPackagerArgs: []
     * ]
     */

    project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js",
        enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    ]

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

    /**
     * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
     *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
     *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
     * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
     * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
     * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
     */
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

    /**
     * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
     */
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

    /**
     * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
     *
     * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
     * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
     *
     * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
     * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
     * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
     * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
     */
    def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

    /**
     * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
     *
     * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
     * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
     * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
     */
    def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.frontend"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
            }
        }
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file('debug.keystore')
                storePassword 'android'
                keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                keyPassword 'android'
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }

            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':react-native-beacons-manager')
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
     implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
     implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')


        if (enableHermes) {
            def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
            debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
            releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
            implementation jscFlavor
        }
    }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
    // apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    //googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
```

and my **package.json** file:

```js
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-beacons-manager": "github:MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager",
    "react-native-bluetooth-status": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.19.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
  }
}
```

Comment: please try cd android and ./gradlew build

Comment: i tried but same error occured (./gradlew clean also tries to build the project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm yes.. `npx react-native run-android` worked after following these steps:

1. restarting the laptop (even though it had just been powered on)
2. `cd android`
3. `./gradlew clean` (worked after restart...)

seems like the simple old ways do worth a try once in a while